# python create single thread to do one task then quit

Tags: python

I am runing a web project.
I want to start a thread to do one job if some event happen.
Before,I always write multithreading program.Such as below

```
class FetchThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, profile_queue):
        ....
    def run(self):
        while true:
        ....
```

But here is only one task,I don't want a thread running all the time.
I want the thread just do one thing, then quit.But I always see others write `while True`  in `Thread.run`, I don't know if method 2 is a good way .Anyone can help?

1.

```
class FetchThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, profile_queue):
        ....
    def stop(self):
        self.__running = False
    def run(self):
        while self.__running:
        ....
        self.stop()
```

2.

```
class FetchThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, profile_queue):
        ....
    def run(self):
        ....
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can encapsulate your entire task into a single function, you can just use the default `Thread` class and pass the right arguments.

```
def a_task(callback):
    # do your task here
    callback()

def some_callback():
    # some way to notify that the task is completed
    pass


task = Thread(target=a_task,
              kwargs={'callback': some_callback})
task.start()
```

If your web project involves Tornado, [a previous answer I provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22469158/python-tornado-can-only-open-one-page-when-processing/22469835#22469835) might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

Put the job you want to do in a regular function and call it like so:

```
>>> def job_func(arg):
...     do_work(arg)
>>> Thread(target=job_func, args=(arg,)).start()
```